# Import c enum to c++ class definition

Tags: c++, c, enums

I have a class like this:

```
class TType {
 public:
 ...
     enum binary_type {
        bt_a = 0,
        bt_xyz,
        ....
        bt_ak = 10,
        ....
     };
}
```

and I use it in several places, also the enum:

```
   if(var12 == TType::bt_a ) { ....
```

Now I imported a C library which has exactly the same enum (same keys, same values, same size) inside one of it's headerfiles:

```
typedef enum data_types_e {
        bt_a = 0,
        bt_xyz,
        ....
} data_types;
```

How can I define the enum in the c++ class definition to use the declaration of the c headerfile? 
I want to continue using the enum the same way as before (TType::bt_a), and avoid copying the whole enum. Furthermore I don't wont to modify the library (otherwise a preprocessor-macro would do the trick) and I want changes made in the library also be made to the enum in my class.

Neither a typedef inside the c++ class definition nor a type alias (c++11) seem to work in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"How can I define the enum in the c++ class definition to use the declaration of the c headerfile?"*

You can simply reuse the values from the c-style enum:

```
 #include "TheOtherEnum.h"

 ...
     enum binary_type {
        bt_a = ::bt_a,
        bt_xyz = ::bt_xyz,
        ....
        bt_ak = ::bt_ak,
        ....
     };
```

> *"Neither a typedef inside the c++ class definition nor a type alias (c++11) seem to work in this situation."*

Yes these would work to provide the correct enum type, but you'll still need to qualify the values from the global namespace and not for nested to your class.

Comment: Since the enums share not only keys but also the values I find this solution here as ugly as copy pasting the whole enum. What if the library extends the enum? I would have to edit my version of the enum manually. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Dreamcooled Sorry for disgusting you, but at least it's the only solution I know, to keep the values consistent :(. I the library extends the enum you have to extend yours as well (I'd suppose you'll get noticed about such changes).

Comment: "ugly" might be the wrong word for it. I was expecting a somewhat simpler solution, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can make C++ enum dependant of C enum:

```
typedef enum data_types_e {
        bt_a = 0,
        bt_xyz,
        ....
} data_types;

// ...

class TType {
 public:
 ...
     enum binary_type {
        bt_a = bt_a,
        bt_xyz = bt_xyz,
        ....
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, this is an old topic, but better lately than never

```
class TType {
public :
  public:
  ...
  #undef __cplusplus
  #include "yourheaderc.h"
  #define __cplusplus
}
```

maybe with a `typedef binary_type data_types` to preserve your nominations

But this solution is available if your header don't contains syntax C forbidden in C++. I'm currently searching a new solution because there are prototypes in my header that contains something like :

```
void afunction(  unsigned long id,
                 enum T_TYPE type,
                 enum T_CHAR characteristic,
                 unsigned short number,
                 unsigned short value);
```

because T_TYPE and T_CHAR are not typedef-ed but this syntax is non-sense in C++ because it's the declaration syntax. So my solution is not appropriate if you are in a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

**If possible**, try renaming your class `TType` say, `class TType_1`.

```
//=============CLibraryFileContainingEnum.h=================
typedef enum data_types_e
{
    bt_a = 9999,
    bt_xyz
} data_types;
//==========================================================

//==========================================================
class TType_1
{
    public:
    enum binary_type
    {
        bt_a = 8878,
        bt_xyz
    };
};
namespace TType
{
    #include "CLibraryFileContainingEnum.h"
}

int main()
{
    int a = TType::bt_a; //this prints 9999
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
//==========================================================
```